# Replace entire dataframe value , if the existing value starts with substring

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

A pandas `dataframe` has values starting with keyword '`make`'. If the values starts with '`make`', then it should be replaced as value '`Yes`'.
How to achieve this using `python 3.x` code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with `^` for start of string:

```
df = df.replace('^make', 'Yes', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# with python 2.7 but should equally work in 3
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1' : ['make','or','break'],
    'col2' : ['make ','me','sweat']})

print df

df = df.applymap(lambda v: 'Yes' if v[:4] == 'make' else v)

print df
```